# How can I install python3.6 on M2 Mac air in Conda

Tags: python, deep-learning, conda

I should use python 3.6 version because I need to load imageatm package and It supports python 3.6.
conda create -n ~~~ python=3.6 makes error line like
The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python=3.6

Therefore I configure channel Conda-forge but still not working.

First I installed Conda, I could install python 3.6 But now it doesn't. Idk what I did...

Comment: Why would you try to install a version of Python that isn't supported by Python anymore? The oldest still in support version of Python is 3.7, and that's for only another 10 weeks. Instead, probably find a library that does the same job, but for current Python?

Comment: Actually Im college student and Professor said only use python 3.6

Comment: Then your professor needs to maybe be told about the fact that Python 3.6 support [ended over a year ago](https://devguide.python.org/versions/), and conda [dropped support for it a few months later](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.13.0), almost a year ago.

Comment: I'd advise using `pyenv` to install v3.6 in a virtual environment, that way you can use it at your convinience and it doesn't affect the system environment.

Comment: Thanks for advice but I can't... Now, I installed python3.6 by Conda install python=3.6 -c pkgs/main. But now there's another error : zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3.6 run.py
run.py is deep learning code which importing imageatm packages.
Can you guys advice this problem..??

Comment: Same as duplicate, but `python=3.6`. It'll run in emulation mode, but that's the best you can hope for.